# ansible module syntax - what does the | after a module name mean?

Tags: ansible, yaml

Here is an example:

```
- name: create the thing
  command: |
    psql -c "create role thingy with login encrypted password 'somepassword';"
```

What is the `|` character for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a yaml block header. `|` is a multiline block scalar header. Every indented lines below will be kept as is with a new line at the end.

In your above case, it is exactly equivalent to:

```
  command: "psql -c \"create role thingy with login encrypted password 'somepassword';\""
```

As demonstrated above, one advantage of such a block is that it removes one level of quote escaping (which is quite helpful for scripts).

There is also a folded block scalar header (`>`) and you can add modifiers for chomping (e.g. `-`)

You'll get a good understanding in seconds on this site: https://yaml-multiline.info/. You can also globally [learn yaml in y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) (one of my favorite ref)